# Data about worldwide import tax rates

Tags: finance, global, taxes, trade

Is there a dataset available that contains data about import tax around the world?

- Problem with most of such "data" is that they come in form of thick booklets full of regulations and nothing to parse
- I'm looking for a parseable dataset to get the general idea about import tax rates, single number per country would probably be enough
- I'm not interested in the regulatory specifics

Comment: https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/TM.TAX.MRCH.WM.AR.ZS?page=5, http://tariffdata.wto.org/ReportersAndProducts.aspx, https://www.wto.org/english/res_e/publications_e/world_tariff_profiles17_e.htm